# What is causing a from error in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I would like to make a form with bootstrap.

I don't know why the second one causes an error.
What kind of things do you think could be the cause?

```
    //OK
    <form action="{{ route('contact_confirm') }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" type="submit">Send</button></div>
        <input id="title" type="text" name = "title"  />
        <input id="title" type="text" name = "body"  />
    </form>
```

```
    //NG
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <form id="contactForm" 　action="{{ route('contact_confirm') }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                        <label>TITLE</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" name = "title" placeholder="Title" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                        <label>CONTENTS</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" name ="body" placeholder="Message" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What form error are you referring to?

Comment: explain about the error

Comment: You know that errors aren't just random messages, yep? They mean something. Actually reading it avoids most of StackOverflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange that you didn't provide any error log or any kind of a message what so ever. However, your problem is exactly here:

`action=`

In the opening form, remove the extra two spaces *The second one is a hidden not accepted character*